# Posting to SAML to ADFS SP server with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on, saml, adfs

Can anyone give me a strategy or example of how to post SAML 2.0 (as an IDP) to a 3rd party/vendor ADFS server (as the SP) using Asp.net?

Or if someone could recommend either a component or Microsoft API that can talk to an external ADFS server.

I'm looking to do this with asp.net in order to save money!

thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

If ADFS is the RP, then just federate ADFS and the IDP using the SAML 2.0 protocol.

Or use [Kentor](https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices). There are also some NuGet OWIN SAML packages.